# JSON Streaming in chunks using Alamofire Swift

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

How to request using Alamofire to get stream JSON. I am using the below function to get the response

```
self.sessionManager?.request(url, method: methodType!, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                if (response.result.error == nil) {
                    completion(response.result.value as AnyObject?, nil , response.response?.statusCode )
                } else {
                    // debugPrint("HTTP Request failed: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    completion(nil, response.result.error, response.response?.statusCode)
                }
        }
```

And my API Url something like

> http://{server Url}/services/data/{number of chunks}/{items in per chunk}

and the response I get from API if the number of chunks is 3 and items per chunk is 3

```
data: [
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026419,

    },
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    },
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    }
]

data: [
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    },
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    },
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    }
]

data: [
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    },
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    },
    {
        "invalidDraft": false,
        "bulkReserve": false,
        "srNo": 0,
        "returned": false,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "timestamp": 1580186026417,
    }
]

data:done
```

I did not get any response from the server but in Postman it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive streaming data, you can try adding

```
request.stream(closure: { data in ... })
```

Inside closure you should collect data chunks from server and parse them lately, after response is called.
In that case response will be nil.

So it would be something like:

```
let mData = NSMutableData()

self.sessionManager?
    .request(url, method: methodType!, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .validate()       
    .stream(closure: { data in mData.append(data) })
    .response { response in
       //parse mData
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your request fails might be that you are using `responseJSON` to parse the response, and the response does not seem to be valid json.

The returned data consists of three individual arrays named `data`, all located at the top level. How should this be converted to a dictionary or array?

Is it possible to change the way the server formats the response, to - for example - have it return one toplevel array, with several `data` child arrays (one for each chunk)? Sort of like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026419
        },
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        },
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        },
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        },
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        }
    ],
    [
         {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        },
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        },
        {
            "invalidDraft": false,
            "bulkReserve": false,
            "srNo": 0,
            "returned": false,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "timestamp": 1580186026417
        }
    ]
]
```

If this is not possible, parse the response as a string instead, and then use regular expression to find every "data" array in the string, which can then be parsed as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating a little on Alex's most helpful answer:

```
fileprivate lazy var alamoSession: Session = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
    configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
    return Alamofire.Session(configuration: configuration /*, interceptor: interceptor*/)
}()

fileprivate func alamofireChunked () {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://A_Steaming_Source.com")    // Put your datasource here
    else {
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    alamoSession.streamRequest(urlRequest).validate().responseStream { response in
        if let data = response.value {
            print("received \(data.count) bytes")
            if data.count > 0 {
                // process received data here
            }
        } else {
            switch response.event {
            case .complete( _):
                // perform any post processing here
                print("stream is finished")
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is working, but I tried adding `parameters` and `headers` and got an error - "Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable'". I can't figure out what's wrong.
`AF.streamRequest(url, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)`

Comment: Hi Shockii - can you post all of your code?